# Jsp, Servelet, web.xml, TomCat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web.xml

I have written a class in java that will be called from a JSP file, I already have Servlet mapping defined in the web.xml file (there is already an existing jsp project), my question is Do I have to define a new servlet mapping to point to my class.
Here is content is the web,xml file:

```
     <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>

     <servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>

  </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>

       <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>

       <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>



   <mime-mapping>

    <extension>ico</extension>

    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>

   </mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From JSP you can directly access the Java class(by creating instance probably). only servlets need mapping in web.xml.(All servlets must be mapped to a url) If you want a servelt to be invoked from JSP then use requestDispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to add anything to your web.xml as long as you just want to use your new class in the JSP file.
Are you sure that this

```
<servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>
```

is correct? Do you have your Test class in the default package ? It's not a good practice.